# I am not getting the difference between print statement and the return statement

Tags: printing, return

I'm trying to find the first letter of every word of a given string.

When I use print statement:

```
def first(s):
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] != ' ':
        if i == 0:
            print(s[i], end =' ')
        elif s[i-1] == ' ':
            print(s[i])
```

Output I receive:

H W

None

But when I use the return statement, I get this:

H W

Code:

```
def first(s):
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] != ' ':
        if i == 0:
            print(s[i], end =' ')
        elif s[i-1] == ' ':
            return s[i]
```

Could anyone tell me what is happening here? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement refers to the output that the function generates and passes back to the line that called the function. As an analogy, you can think of a function as a black box machine that takes input (the arguments you pass into the function), processes that input, and generates an output that will then handed back to wherever the function was called from. But that does not make the return value appear on the screen; for that, you need `print()`, which makes the argument passed to it appear on the screen. Once you have received a return value from a function, you can `print` it, but without doing it, it won't appear on the screen.

So in your second example, you can use `print(first(s))` in the main program to print. The `first(s)` inside the parentheses of the print function are the function call, and the return value of that function call will be what you defined inside the function via `return`; this will then be printed via the `print()` inside which it's nested. Alternatively, if you find it more intuitive, you can assign the return value of the function to a new variable and print that:

```
x = first(s)
print(x)
```

Lastly, you can also put the `print()` inside the function and print from there; this would be called a side effect of the function (an effect of the function other than returning a value:

```
def first(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] != ' ':
            if i == 0:
                print(s[i], end =' ')
            elif s[i-1] == ' ':
                print(s[i])
```

In your case, the function definition is a bit odd, because you print via a side effect in one case of the `if` but `return` in the case of the `elif`. It'd be better to use the same in both cases.

Comment: Yeah that was helpful. Thank you.

Edit: But when I will be using either print or return in both the if and elif  cases, I don't get the output I want.  I mean when I'll be using return statement for both if and elif, I will not be able to return the both values(Idk what I'm missing here). And when I'll be using print on both if and elif statement I receive "None" as an additional output.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly your function is supposed to do? It simply returns the first letter of a word? Does it take one word, or a string with several words in it, as input?

Comment: Yeah. It returns the first letter of an inputted string(let's say Hello World). It should return H and W

Comment: If that’s what you want to do, then you could simply `.split()` the string into words to get a list of the words in it, create an empty list of first letters,  loop over the list of words with `for word in list_of_words: list_of_first_letters.append(word[0])` and return list_of_first_letters

Comment: Ahh! That was super helpful. Thanks so much. However, I'd like to know why my code gives me the output as represented.